# Where can I find a fusion chart?

Tags: devil-survivor-2

Are the fusion combinations for Devil Survivor 2 the same as that of the first game?  If not, where can I find an updated fusion chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've taken this information from the Japanese strategy guide and various Japanese DS2 [wikis](http://wikinavi.net/ds2/index.php?2%E8%BA%AB%E5%90%88%E4%BD%93).

Here is a *looooong* list of fusions, broken down by tribe:

**Omega**

```
Vile + Megami, 
Snake + Deity, 
Tyrant + Megami, 
Tyrant + Fallen, 
Touki + Kishin, 
Fiend + Tyrant, 
Hero + Vile, 
Hero + Kishin
```

**Megami**

```
Divine + Deity, 
Divine + Snake, 
Fallen + Snake, 
Fallen + Avian, 
Avatar + Divine, 
Genma + Omega, 
Fairy + Avatar, 
Kishin + Omega, 
Femme + Omega, 
Femme + Divine, 
Fiend + Snake, 
Fiend + Avian, 
Fiend + Femme, 
Hero + Omega, 
Hero + Divine, 
Hero + Femme
```

**Deity**

```
Snake + Vile,
Divine + Omega,
Avatar + Snake,
Genma + Snake,
Tyrant + Omega,
Tyrant + Vile,
Tyrant + Divine,
Kishin + Avian,
Kishin + Avatar,
Ghost + Vile,
Fiend + Genma,
Hero + Snake,
Hero + Avatar,
Hero + Genma
```

**Vile**

```
Omega + Megami,
Dragon + Deity,
Avian + Snake,
Fallen + Omega,
Genma + Wilder,
Tyrant + Deity,
Tyrant + Genma,
Kishin + Fairy,
Ghost + Megami,
Ghost + Kishin,
Fiend + Omega,
Fiend + Divine,
Fiend + Avatar,
Fiend + Kishin
```

**Snake**

```
Avian + Divine,
Avatar + Megami,
Wilder + Avian,
Genma + Avatar,
Fairy + Deity,
Fairy + Avian,
Kishin + Genma,
Touki + Wilder,
Touki + Tyrant,
Ghost + Avatar,
Fiend + Dragon,
Fiend + Beast,
Hero + Beast,
Hero + Tyrant
```

**Dragon**

```
Vile + Omega,
Beast + Vile,
Wilder + Fallen,
Genma + Divine,
Tyrant + Snake,
Tyrant + Beast,
Jaki + Wilder,
Femme + Deity,
Femme + Fallen,
Ghost + Snake,
Fiend + Wilder
```

**Divine**

```
Avian + Megami,
Avatar + Avian,
Beast + Avatar,
Genma + Avian,
Fairy + Fallen,
Kishin + Snake,
Jaki + Snake,
Femme + Megami,
Femme + Avian,
Ghost + Genma,
Hero + Dragon,
Hero + Avian
```

**Avian**

```
Divine + Vile,
Fallen + Vile,
Beast + Deity,
Fairy + Wilder,
Kishin + Beast,
Touki + Megami,
Touki + Fallen,
Jaki + Dragon,
Jaki + Genma,
Ghost + Divine
```

**Fallen**

```
Divine + Dragon,
Wilder + Omega,
Genma + Dragon,
Fairy + Dragon,
Tyrant + Avatar,
Kishin + Tyrant,
Femme + Fairy,
Ghost + Jaki,
Wilder + Vile,
Femme + Snake
```

**Avatar**

```
Divine + Megami,
Beast + Omega,
Beast + Snake,
Beast + Divine,
Wilder + Divine,
Fairy + Divine,
Tyrant + Avian,
Touki + Genma,
Jaki + Avian,
Femme + Wilder,
Hero + Wilder
```

**Beast**

```
Fallen + Dragon,
Genma + Megami,
Fairy + Snake,
Fairy + Genma,
Touki + Divine,
Touki + Avian,
Touki + Fairy,
Jaki + Fallen,
Femme + Jaki,
Ghost + Avian
```

**Wilder**

```
Dragon + Snake,
Avatar + Omega,
Genma + Deity,
Fairy + Megami,
Tyrant + Fairy,
Touki + Dragon,
Jaki + Touki,
Femme + Tyrant,
Ghost + Dragon,
Ghost + Beast
```

**Genma**

```
Beast + Megami,
Beast + Avian,
Wilder + Dragon,
Kishin + Dragon,
Touki + Vile,
Jaki + Vile,
Jaki + Kishin,
Femme + Avatar,
Femme + Kishin,
Ghost + Touki,
Fiend + Fallen,
Fiend + Jaki,
Hero + Fairy,
Hero + Jaki
```

**Fairy**

```
Snake + Megami,
Wilder + Megami,
Kishin + Deity,
Touki + Beast,
Jaki + Avatar,
Femme + Beast,
Femme + Touki,
Ghost + Deity,
Ghost + Fallen,
Ghost + Femme,
Fiend + Ghost
```

**Tyrant**

```
Deity + Omega,
Vile + Deity,
Dragon + Vile,
Fallen + Divine,
Avatar + Vile,
Genma + Fallen,
Jaki + Deity,
Femme + Vile,
Fiend + Deity,
Hero + Megami,
Hero + Fallen
```

**Kishin**

```
Deity + Megami,
Snake + Omega,
Avian + Omega,
Fallen + Deity,
Genma + Vile,
Touki + Deity,
Touki + Snake,
Touki + Avatar,
Jaki + Omega,
Jaki + Divine,
Fiend + Vile,
Fiend + Touki,
Hero + Deity,
Hero + Touki
```

**Touki**

```
Dragon + Omega,
Avatar + Fallen,
Wilder + Deity,
Wilder + Snake,
Fairy + Vile,
Kishin + Megami,
Jaki + Beast,
Femme + Genma,
Ghost + Omega,
Ghost + Wilder
```

**Jaki**

```
Dragon + Megami,
Avian + Vile,
Avatar + Deity,
Beast + Dragon,
Wilder + Avatar,
Genma + Beast,
Tyrant + Wilder,
Kishin + Vile,
Kishin + Fallen,
Ghost + Fairy
```

**Femme**

```
Avian + Deity,
Avian + Dragon,
Fallen + Megami,
Beast + Fallen,
Fairy + Beast,
Kishin + Divine,
Touki + Omega,
Jaki + Megami,
Jaki + Tyrant,
Ghost + Tyrant,
Fiend + Fairy,
Hero + Ghost
```

**Ghost**

```
Avatar + Dragon,
Wilder + Beast,
Fairy + Omega,
Tyrant + Dragon,
Kishin + Wilder,
Jaki + Fairy,
Femme + Dragon,
Hero + Fiend
```

If you combine two demons of the same tribe you will get an **Element** demon:

**Erthys (Earth)**

```
Fallen + Fallen
Wilder + Wilder
Tyrant + Tyrant
Jaki + Jaki
Ghost + Ghost
```

**Aeros (Air)**

```
Vile + Vile
Divine + Divine
Avian + Avian
Genma + Genma
Fairy + Fairy
```

**Aquans (Aqua)**

```
Megami + Megami
Snake + Snake 
Avatar + Avatar 
Kishin + Kishin
Femme + Femme 
Fiend + Fiend
```

**Flaemis (Flame)**

```
Omega + Omega 
Deity + Deity 
Dragon + Dragon 
Beast + Beast 
Touki + Touki 
Hero + Hero
```

Here is the **Mitama** fusion chart (unlocked in the New Game+):

**Saki Mitama (VIT)**

```
Flaemis + Aquans
```

**Kusi Mitama (AGI)**

```
Aquans + Flaemis
Aeros + Aquans
```

**Ara Mitama (STR)**

```
Erthys + Aquans 
Aeros + Flaemis
```

**Nigi Mitama (MAG)**

```
Erthys + Aeros
```

There are specific and unique demon combinations, but they are too numerous to name. xP

Comment: interesting... Mitamas huh